# PyQt5 how to destroy last widget when clicked 'OK' button on QMessageBox created by a button on that widget

Tags: python, python-3.4, qwidget, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I have a QMainWindow that have a button, when clicked this button, another widget pops up. This widget have a button, when clicked this button an alert message pops up. When I press 'OK' on that message button, only QMessageBox is closing, small widget is still open. I want to close that widget when I press 'OK' on that message button. I couldn't figure out how can I do this. Here is my code;

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMessageBox,QApplication, QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton,
                             QDesktopWidget, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QToolBar, QVBoxLayout,
                             QComboBox,QLabel,QLineEdit,QGridLayout,QMenuBar,QMenu,QStatusBar,
                             QTextEdit,QDialog,QFrame,QProgressBar,QHBoxLayout
                             )
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon,QFont,QPixmap,QPalette,QWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt,QBasicTimer, QTimer,QPoint
import PyQt5.QtWidgets,PyQt5.QtCore
import time,random,subprocess,sys,json


class cssden(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFixedSize(600,500)

        #Other widget button
        self.owidget = QPushButton(self)
        self.owidget.clicked.connect(self.second_widget)

        self.show()

    #other widget
    #I want to destroy this widget when I press 'OK' on the QMessageBox
    def second_widget(self):
        self.w_window = QWidget()
        self.w_window.setGeometry(650,300,600,300)
        self.w_window.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue")

        self.w_button = QPushButton(self.w_window)
        self.w_button.setText("Alert")
        self.w_button.clicked.connect(self.alert)


        self.w_window.show()
    #alert from second widget
    def alert(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self.w_window,"Alert","Alert message")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color: rgb(30,30,30);border: 1px solid black}")

ex = cssden()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried to connect them ('OK' button of QMessageBox and last widget) but I couldn't do it very well and I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution by myself, just make a QMessageBox(no inherit), then find the result and check if the result is something you want, `close()` the widget.

```
self.result1 = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information,"Alert","Alert message",QMessageBox.Ok)
self.result1.setGeometry(500,500,500,500)
self.result1.show()

result = self.result1.exec_()
if result == 1024:
    self.w_window.close()
```

I used 'OK' button so when I printed `result` the value was `1024`, so before you check which button clicked (if you use yes|no buttons) print the result first then find the value, then do your job.